# How to use Gmail Rest API to send emails?

Tags: android, rest, email, firebase, gmail-api

I want to use this API [https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users//messages/send](http://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users//messages/send) to send emails from my android app to different users emails to verify their accounts, reset passwords, etc.., 
I tried to read the documentation but I did not understand anything.

Comment: So, where is the question?

Comment: why you think that you will understand anything from us, if you `tried to read the documentation but I did not understand anything`?

Answer (score 1):

Creating an email message can be greatly simplified with the MimeMessage class in the javax.mail.internet package. The following example shows how to create the email message, including the headers:

```
public static MimeMessage createEmail(String to,
                                          String from,
                                          String subject,
                                          String bodyText)
            throws MessagingException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);

        email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(to));
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setText(bodyText);
        return email;
    }
```

Once you have created a message, you can send it by supplying it in the request body of a call to messages.send, as demonstrated in the following examples:

```
public static Message sendMessage(Gmail service,
                                      String userId,
                                      MimeMessage emailContent)
            throws MessagingException, IOException {
        Message message = createMessageWithEmail(emailContent);
        message = service.users().messages().send(userId, message).execute();

        System.out.println("Message id: " + message.getId());
        System.out.println(message.toPrettyString());
        return message;
    }
```

Further readings:

- https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending
- https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-the-gmail-api--cms-22841
- https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android

Comment: I tried this and it gets me an syntax error in this line: message = service.users().messages().send(userId, message).execute();